# How to write it as the linear process for MA(2) when the characteristic root is complex?

Tags: forecasting, arima, moving-average

I have MA(2) as
$$x_t=e_t-0.3e_{t-1}+0.1e_{t-2}$$
and would like to find $x_{t+1}$. But I struggle and
$$x_t(1-0.3B+0.1B^2)^{-1}=e_t.$$
I can't write it as linear process because the root of the equation is complex. In here I try to find the best linear predictor of $F_{t+1}$.

Comment: You need to eloborate on what you have tried.  While the roots are complex, the coefficients of the $\operatorname{AR}(\infty)$ representation will no be complex.  Also add self-study tag.

Comment: Can't you give me more hint? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- To obtain $x_{t+1}$, increase the time index by 1 for every member of the first equation.
- To obtain a forecast that targets the conditional mean of $x_{t+1}$, take the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(\cdot|I_t)$ of that equation. ($I_t$ is the information set up to and including time $t$.)